# Any way to have strongly typed use of Navigator?

Tags: flutter, dart, strong-typing, flutter-navigation

I have a `MaterialButton` with the following `onPressed` field:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
    final int intResult = await showMyDialog(context, provider.myArg) ?? 0;
    //...
}
```

Here is the `showMyDialog` function:

```dart
Future<int?> showMyDialog(BuildContext context, Object someArg) async {
  return showDialog<int>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
        create: (_) => MyProvider(someArg),
        child: MyDialog(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

---

Now the problem I see is that in `MyDialog` (a `StatelessWidget`), I need to use `Navigator.pop(...)` to return a value for the awaited `intResult`. However, I can't seem to find a way to strongly type these calls, and so it's hard to be certain that no runtime type error will happen.

The best I have right now, which is admittedly a bit inconvenient, is to subclass `StatelessWidget` and wrap the `Navigator` functions in it:

```dart
abstract class TypedStatelessWidget<T extends Object> extends StatelessWidget {
  void pop(BuildContext context, [T? result]) {
    Navigator.pop(context, result);
  }
}
```

Then in a `TypedStatelessWidget<int>` we can use `pop(context, 0)` normally, and `pop(context, 'hi')` will be marked as a type error by the editor. This still doesn't link the dialog return type and the navigator, but at least it avoids manually typing each navigator call.

---

Is there any better way to have this strongly typed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I ended up doing. Essentially, this allows for a widget type and a provider type to be "tied together". This way, when the custom `pop` function is called in the dialog, there is a type contract (see `PopType`) for what the return value should be. There is also support for non-manual pop navigation by using `WillPopScope`, which gets the typed provider's return function and arguments (see the abstract functions in `TypedProvider`) to properly pass that value up the widget tree.

````dart
mixin TypedWidget<T, N extends TypedProvider<T>?> on Widget {
  ChangeNotifierProvider<N> asTypedWidget(
      BuildContext context, N Function(BuildContext) createProviderFunc) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<N>(
        create: createProviderFunc,
        builder: (BuildContext innerContext, _) {
          return WillPopScope(
              child: this,
              onWillPop: () {
                final N provider = Provider.of<N>(innerContext, listen: false);
                if (provider == null) {
                  return Future<bool>.value(true);
                }
                provider.onPopFunction(provider.getPopFunctionArgs());
                return Future<bool>.value(true);
              });
        });
  }

  /// Builds this TypedWidget inside `showDialog`.
  ///
  /// The `TypedProvider`'s `onPopFunction` is called if the
  /// dialog is closed outside of a manual `Navigator.pop()`. This doesn't have
  /// a return type; all returning actions should be done inside the defined
  /// `onPopFunction` of the provider.
  ///
  /// Example:
  /// ```
  /// MyTypedWidget().showTypedDialog(
  ///   context,
  ///   (BuildContext context) => MyTypedProvider(...)
  /// );
  /// ```
  Future<void> showTypedDialog(
      BuildContext context, N Function(BuildContext) createProviderFunc,
      {bool barrierDismissible = true}) async {
    await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
      builder: (_) => asTypedWidget(context, createProviderFunc),
    );
  }
}

abstract class TypedProvider<PopType> with ChangeNotifier {
  TypedProvider(this.onPopFunction);

  Function(PopType) onPopFunction;
  PopType getPopFunctionArgs();

  void pop(BuildContext context) {
    onPopFunction(getPopFunctionArgs());
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
````

There are most likely other ways to achieve that, and this solution certainly has some constraints, but it effectively provides strong typing to the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the `Navigator.pop` method as you can type its return value.

```dart
Navigator.pop<int>(context, 1);
```

I let you refer to the [pop method documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) for more details.

Comment: The problem with this is even though you use `Navigator.pop<int>`, if you use `showDialog<bool>`, you get no error at edit time. So the typing on `pop` is essentially pointless.

Comment: You won't be able to get this kind of error by using showDialog.You might as well recode showDialog from scratch to work with your TypedStatelessWidget class so the builder property expects a return of type TypedStatelessWidget<T>.

Comment: Well if that is indeed the only way, I might as well try. It would still leave me wondering why people should accept this gap between the typings; sounds more like a javascript/pythonic way to do things where you just trust that the dialog types match the navigation values.